# Can you run VBA excel without having Enable all macros checked

Tags: excel, vba

My boss wants me to have a formula to black out 5 check boxes if one excel Check box =TRUE. However working with a large company I cannot Enable all macros for security reasons. I do have the Trust access to the VBA checked. My code is all VBA and works but after saving it and reopening it, it no longer works. The file type is macro-enable. IS this a Security issue or am I doing something incorrect?

-Saved file under macro-Enable
-Checked the VBA trust module box
-Code was working
-no pop up errors upon opening and closing
-The formula is to change it from an unchecked character box to a checked and vise versa due to other circumstances

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As 
Boolean)
If Target.Column = 15 Then
    If Target.Value = Chr(254) Then
        Target.Value = Chr(168)
        Cancel = True
    ElseIf Target.Value = Chr(168) Then
        Target.Value = Chr(254)
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like using conditional formatting with some forms would resolve your issue without having to use macros.

Comment: The option most typically used where macros are not totally disabled is "Disable all macros with notification" - this means you must allow macros to run when prompted.  "Trust access to VB project" is only needed if you want to interact programmatically with the VBA modules and is not relevant for your case.

Comment: *I do have the Trust access to the VBA checked* - why? You only need to *allow programmatic access to the VBIDE API* if you are planning to write VBA code *that can write and/or rewrite other VBA code, or even itself* - if you're not meta-programming, that box should be left unchecked.

Comment: I built a quick example of shading/with conditional formatting in this excel sheet (no vba). It may not quite satisfy the requirement, but you might be able to come up with a solution with somethings similar. https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9gf5ZGqw0A3tPT22QYA

Comment: Thank you for your help and clarity! I will be trying to work on some conditional formatting but mostly ill be contacting the Security Team since this is the root of the problem!

Comment: Well if you only want to run code allowed by you, then you probably need to obtain a digital certificate that you can use for signing approved VBA code. Every time this code is modified, it will invalidate the certificate and would need to be re-signed. That's probably as close as you'll get to what you're asking.

Comment: Angela, there is an option in the Trust Center about "trusted locations". These are folders you (or your admin) can mark as "trusted" and any Office files containing macros that are saved there should work. This is more secure than the general (older) options about letting all macros run, or being prompted to allow code to run.